# Chromedriver won't open in headless mode using Selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Im using selenium and the chromedriver and trying to open it in headless mode.I have followed all directions from original documentation , I have the latest version of chromedriver(2.29,which is supposed to support headless mode) and still chromedriver will open the chrome browser like it normally would do(browser window shows up).

Here is the snippet of code im using:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_args=['--headless','--disable-gpu','--remote-debugging-port=9222','--ignore-ssl-errors=true','--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'])
driver.set_window_size(800,600)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
driver.quit()
```

Can you explain why is this happening and if possible suggest a solution?

Comment: Are you on windows by any chance, as [I don't believe that headless mode is supported yet on Windows](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)? That is not to say that it's impossible, it will just require an [external library](https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win).

Comment: Yes Im on Windows 7.The final script will run on a linux machine but i wanted to test it out.

Comment: As I said, headless mode isn't supported on Windows. If you want to test it out I'd recommend running a lightweight linux system from a USB stick or a virtual computer :-)

Comment: Yes I used a virtual machine running Ubuntu.The problem is that it still din't work.I had to use xvfb to get it to work.Anyways thanks for the help.